# Docker hello-world container not visible with docker ps command

Tags: docker

I succefully ran hello-world using docker run command , but when I check running containers with docker ps , this container was not visble under running containers ,
Any suggestions

Thank
Rajendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `hello-world` image from docker has no extra service running inside it so therefore exits after printing the default text. As such you cannot view it using `docker ps` which is command for viewing currently running containers.

To view running/stopped containers, run `docker ps -a`

See the image on how the `docker ps` and `docker ps -a` command show different results for the `hello-world image.

[image: Docker]

Answer (score 2):

How did you run it? If I remember correctly, the hello world example just echos and quits, so running `docker ps` immediately afterwards won't show you anything.

Try this instead:

```
docker ps -n 1
```

That will essentially show you the most recent container you ran and its state.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, if you really want to watch the `hello-world` execution at runtime...

Open up a **new** terminal window and run the command `docker events`, then keep watching what happens when you run `docker run hello-world` in your original terminal window.

Magically, you will see your entire container life-cycle below:

1.`container create` (notice the funny `name=` attribute of your ephemeral container name)
2.`image pull`
3.`container init`
4.`container start`
5.`container attach`
6.`container died`
7.`container cleanup`

**Enjoy!**